# Optimizely is not changing variation after clearing cookies

Tags: cookies, optimizely

I have two variations in my experiment with the following traffic allocation percentages:

1) Original (0%)
2) Variation #1 (100%)

The site is always showing the original, even though its traffic allocation is 0%. It should always show Variation #1. The only way I can see Variation #1 is by forcing it to run using the instructions at https://help.optimizely.com/QA_Campaigns_and_Experiments/Force_a_specific_variation_to_run_in_Optimizely_Classic.

The issue I am experiencing has the "Solved" status at https://community.optimizely.com/t5/Using-Optimizely/How-to-force-Optimizely-to-change-the-variation-Clearing-cookies/td-p/7758, but clearing cookies is not working for me.

Maybe Optimizely is using parameters other than cookies to determine which variation to show? It still does not make sense to me because my traffic allocation is 100% for Variation #1. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my "URL Targeting" configuration. It is fixed now and everything works properly.